# Activity diagram final node in errors

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I would like to ask, if a final node in some activity can represent two different outcomes.

For example in use case `buy premium account` I can have two outcomes: IF I have enough credit then I will end the activity with bought premium account ELSE I end the activity with some error page that the user doesn't have enough credit.

Can I use the same final node in this case?

Comment: Given that an activity final node is the end of a _flow_ then to have two flows merging on that node is wrong: final node has only one "input". The point however is that decision is made BEFORE the final node in a decision node (eventually followed by two activities to display, for example, something to end-user). Final node is just to _say_ that flow ends there.

Comment: So final node only says that my flow ends and technically it doesn't matter if it is a main flow or alternative flow?

Comment: Yes, it stops all the activities but it does not _do_ anything else. Technically everyone will understand that node to have multiple inputs but it (IMO) defeats the purpose to have multiple termination nodes (as you may have or not multiple exit points in a function...)

Comment: Can you somehow write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with something like the image [image: two actions and a final node]

More see the comment about [image: figure 15.44] in UML specification: "In Figure 15.44, two ways to reach an ActivityFinalNode exist; but it is the result of exclusive “or” branching, not a “race” situation like the example in Figure 15.43. This example uses two Activity FinalNodes, which has the same semantics as using one with two incoming edges."

It means that a FinalNodes may have two incoming edges, and the norm explains that the first flow which reaches the FinalNode terminates the activity what ever the other flow, and there is something special for output activity parameters.

Comment: Can two control flows go to a final node? Isn't the merge node necessary?

Comment: for me not because only one path can be follow one flow only : right site or left side but not the both. This is different than to merge parallel flows without synchronization.